# Dropbox says version 2.10 is too old. Why?

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

I just tried to install Dropbox from both deb and source. But I'm still getting this error message. Is v2.10 really old? Or what can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Do you tried ``apt-get update`` in the console for see if appears a new version of Dropbox? (Due im not using Ubuntu since 3 weeks ago... I can't say if exist a new version or it's a mistake from Dropbox)

Comment: Yes, nothing's there.

Comment: My version is 42.2.114. I installed mine following instructions at https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux in the section titled "Dropbox Headless Install via command line".

Comment: It worked. thanks. I'd accept if you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My version is currently at 42.2.114. I installed mine following instructions at https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux in the section titled "Dropbox Headless Install via command line".

There are just two commands that need to be run. I have a 64-bit system and so I used:

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

and, after moving to `~/.dropbox-dist`

```
dropboxd
```

Dropbox installed this way updates automatically and starts, by default, automatically.

Comment: @user68186 That didn't work. That deb file is too old. Date is 2015-10-28 https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb